# How to call event of another page from another page in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

My question is very simple but may be strange.
I want to call a event say a button click of an aspx page say abcd.aspx.cs from another page say wxyz.aspx.cs. Is it possible to call the button click event of abcd page from wxyz ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Even though ASP.NET provides a subset of object-oriented APIs it doesn't simply work like you think. You need to understand how the Page LifeCycle works where each page instance is created and destroyed with each request and each request belong to one single page (or resource).

This question is a bit weird and unusual...what are you trying to achieve?